# É possivel alterar código do meu servidor sem precisar de compilação?

Tags: c

Bem eu estava pensando em algo, tenho um programa que é hospedado em linux e através de um executável, os meus clientes tem acesso, toda modificação que eu faço no código do servidor tenho que compilar novamente para entrar em vigor, isso impossibilita os meus clientes a se conectar, dependendo do tempo da manutenção, leva cerca de 4 horas, então eu estava pensando, é possível eu fazer algum forma para eu alterar o código do servidor e as atualizações entrarem em vigor com os clientes logados?

Comment: Nâo dá pra compilar o programa sem pausar o seu servidor? Ou compilar em outro computador e só fazer o upload do executável? Só precisaria pausar pra trocar um executável pelo outro.

Comment: O que exatamente este servidor faz com os clientes e o que os clientes fazem com o servidor?

Answer (score 1):

Então o que está acontecendo, meu amigo, é que você está usando a dinâmica errada para seu servidor.

Respondendo à sua primeira pergunta, não - não há como fazer isso sem compilar pois C não é uma linguagem de script. Justamente por isso maior parte dos servidores utilizam ou PHP ou (ultimamente) Python.

Se você continuar a utilizar C, é recomendável que você utilize uma espécie de árvore de funcionalidades (ex.: o programa carrega várias DLLs e roda cada uma com sua característica própria), assim economiza tempo para alterar o servidor.
É explícito que existem várias maneiras de abordar o caso e, de verdade: **C não é a melhor opção para um servidor que vá ser alterado o tempo todo**. Mesmo assim, como o assunto é vago, deixo assim minha dica.

Answer (score 1):

A **compilação** de um programa **C/C++** envolve três passos principais: `pré-processador`, `compilação` e `linkagem`

- **Pré Processador:**

O **pré-processador** é a primeira etapa da compilação,ele examina o programa fonte escrito e executa certas modificações, baseado nas diretivas de compilação.

- Junta linhas que foram separadas por sequências de escape.
- Remove comentários e os substitui por espaços em branco
- Expande macros
- Processa diretivas de pré-processamento

Portanto, o **pré-processador** modifica o programa fonte, que ainda não estaria pronto para ser entregue ao **compilador**.

- **Compilador:**

O **compilador** processa o resultado do **pré-processador** e para cada unidade compilação gera um arquivo objeto.
ele consiste em verificar se o código esta bem construído segundo a **gramática da linguagem**. Após verificar que não existe qualquer erro 
sintático ou semântico ele já pode então gerar o código em **linguagem de maquina**.

- **Linkagem:**

Finalmente, após **pré-processar**, **compilar** cada arquivo fonte e gerar todos os arquivos objetos podemos invocar o **linker**. 
O **linker** é responsável por juntar todos os arquivos objetos e gerar o **arquivo executável**(pode ser usado também para gerar bibliotecas dinâmicas, como **dlls**).

> Com os dados obtidos acima, temos o conhecimento de como a compilação
>   funciona e como o arquivo exeutável é gerado, e com essa bagagem
>   adquirida percebemos que **NÃO é possível alterar um código executável
>   sem a compilação.**
>
> O que você pode estar fazendo é estabelecer um horário para **MANUTENÇÃO**
>   no seu servidor diária, assim  sempre nesse horário os clientes seriam
>   desconectados e as atualizações seriam feitas!